# Magento 2: event or plugin after filters applied and removed in category pages

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, layered-navigation, plugin

I want to write customization on after filters are applied and filters are removed in category pages.

I need any event or plugin while filter applied or filter removed in Magento 2.3.2.